# Does current mirror circuit have differential gain when there is one \$V_{out}\$?

Tags: gain, current-mirror

The following is from the book [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), page 147:

[image]

What's the gain of this circuit?

Is it \$ \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in1} - V_{in2}}\$,  \$\frac{V_{out}} {V_{in1}}\$ or \$\mbox{ $\Large \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in2}}$ }\$?

The following is the small-signal analysis:

[image]

For the left part of this circuit, we have:

$$-V_{G3} g_{m3} - \frac{V_{G3}} {r_{o3}} = (V_{in1} - V_p) g_{m1} + \frac{V_{G3} - V_p} {r_{o1}}$$

For right part of this circuit, we have

$$-(V_{in2} - V_p) g_{m2} + \frac{V_p - V_{out}} {r_{o2}} = V_{G3} g_{m4} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o4}}$$

We know that the current flowing through M3 and M4 are the same we will have

$$-V_{G3} g_{m3} - \frac{V_{G3}} {r_{o3}} = V_{G3} g_{m4} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o4}}$$

Comment: The PMOS are upside down. What was your question -- just what definition to use? Where does your question relate to the analysis?

Comment: @TimWilliams What's the equation for this gain? Is it \$ \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in1} - V_{in2}}\$,  \$\frac{V_{out}} {V_{in1}}\$ or \$\mbox{ $\Large \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in2}}$ }\$?

Comment: This is a MOSFET differential pair but with an active load instead of resistors. The input is differential, and the output is single-ended (diff to single-ended converter). The output voltage gain is Vout / Vd (Vd is the inputs difference).

Comment: The gain is `1/(1/gm1 + 1/gm2)*2*(ro2 || ro4) = gm*(ro2 || ro4)` as `gm = gm1 = gm2`.  It's much easier if you follow the signal path and calculate the gain without solving any equation.

Comment: @internet What signal path do you mean? Can you draw a schematic for me?

Comment: @kile Please check examples in pages 8 and 10 in the link below. http://tnt.etf.bg.ac.rs/~ms1aik/files/AIC-2020_OTA_1.pdf

Comment: @internet But there is no current source in this schematic and there is a cap in \$V_out\$. https://i.imgur.com/Pijz7pG.png

Comment: @internet There is no need to consider \$r_{ds}\$.

Comment: @G36 Could you please take a look?

Comment: Take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542529/differential-pair-active-load-contradiction/542531#542531

Comment: Also, your equations look good to me. Good job once again. But you need to change your approach and try to learn how to find the voltage gain by inspection. Of course, this will be a simplified expression, not an exact one, but in practice it is sufficient and teaches circuit intuition.